# What is best way to update multipli record in database (800000 row) and persist the new data from csv file using spring bash?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

I have File csv that contains large data,every time the user upload new file the old data will be updated or deleted it depends on the file and save the new data.
I am using Spring bash for this task.
I am creating a job that contains two steps :
first steps : A tasklet for updating the old data
second steps : steps that contains a reader,procssor and writer with chunk data to persist the new data
the problèm is in the time of save and update is very lard 12min for file that contains 80000 row.
can I optimize the time for this job ?

Comment: Bulk load the data into a staging table then use insert and update statements to apply to the final table.

Comment: I think that is the same as I use in the second steps , chunk just handle a block of 2000 and then insert data

Comment: I’m guessing your update will be running row by row. I expect the update part takes longer than the insert part? It would help to post the database code.

Comment: yes the update part take the time , for the code of database I am just using spring data to update old rows activeDATA = Repo.findByIndex(1) and I update the active data by putting -1 in the index

Comment: Do you have the ability to create tables in your database? Will there be only one user doing this at a time? What type of database? Please edit the code and other info into the question

Comment: about database I am using sql server

Comment: So are you able to create new tables in your sql server database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import (export) big data process, update, delete, update using joining to tables, searching process, all these operations very very faster on Databases than on programming languages. I recommended to you these:

1. Use SQL Server `BULK INSERT` command to import data from CSV into Database. For example, for 10 million records this process will be executed in 12 seconds.
2. After importing data you can update, delete or insert new data on the database using joining to import table.
   This is the best way, I think that.